# developing mobile apps for flash, stage size for ios devices

Tags: ios, air, screen-resolution

Ive started building an ios app in flash cs5.5.. i want this app to be available for iphone,ipod,ipad and also the new ipad. My question is in what stage size in flash i have to design my application? Should i must go with the higher resolution that this app will be used 2048x1536 of the new ipad and then use methods like stage.scaleMode
and similar with this in actionscript in order to be viewable in iphone/ipod?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you setting stage.scaleMode to StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE */*setting other scale modes will at least affect performance since you will display and render more elements on the screen then you actually need + it will become a nightmare to adjust your elements sizes for comfortable perseption*/*. So it doesn't matter which document size you select in Flash authoring tool (Flash CS#).

Developing for multiple screen resolutions (and most important here!) densities is a big topic that can't fit into answer. I would recommend you to google it and read some articles or blog posts. Two key things you'll need to use is Stage#stageWidth/stageHeight and Capabilities.screenDPI. And if you work with bitmap assets (images) you will definitely need several versions of them for several DPI ranges.

But again, regarding your question in this form you asked — document size doesn't matter + StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE